# Where does Visual Studio Code look for includePath (C/C++ extensions)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I've found out something pretty strange.

I have WSL/Debian installed on my laptop, as well as MSYS2 (for native Windows development). I have C++ headers installed in both of them: in C:\msys64\...\ for MSYS2 and in %USERPROFILE%\AppData...\someendlesspath...\ for WSL. The second one isn't in the PATH variable.

But strangely, without having configured any includePath variable in VSCode, the C/C++ extension (from Microsoft) automatically detects #include  and if I right-click>Go to definition, it opens the one in AppData\Local... from WSL.

It apparently causes some bugs and collisions for IntelliSense, and makes it incredibly slower than when I didn't have WSL installed, so I would like to be sure that C/C++ extension doesn't look in that path without me asking him to do so.

Answer (score 0):

in order to avoid include path clashes, i had to set the [.vscode/c_cpp_properties.json](https://github.com/sombriks/sample-qt-test/blob/master/.vscode/c_cpp_properties.json) file the desired paths.

Comment: Can you share your c_cpp_properties settings, other than includePath? Even with an includePath defined that points to the stdlib includes I want to use, VSCode is still insisting on showing the WSL ones as well, and seems to be picking them first sometimes.

Comment: And I don't even know how it found this directory. Pretty strange...

Answer (score 0):

After a while of looking with no clear answer, what I found to fix my issue was to change the compiler path from `usr/bin/gcc` to `usr/bin/gcc-11`. It just showed up in the dropdown, so I'd suggest trying the different options available for the compiler path in the drop down menu.